# How to Increment timestamps in text file

Tags: awk, timestamp, notepad++, text-manipulation

I am comparing two long log files which are exactly the same except for the timestamp.

Eg: Log1

```
fn1-start 11:10:10
fn2-start 11:10:12
fn2-end   11:10:19
fn1-end   11:11:20
...
A long list
...
```

Log 2

```
fn1-start 11:22:11
fn2-start 11:22:13
fn2-end   11:22:20
fn1-end   11:23:41
...
A long list
...
```

I want to compare two log files like this to find out which function is causing performance degradation using some comparison tool.

What I want is to increment or decrement all the time stamps in one of the log files. The timestamp of the second file starts with 11:22:11, In my case I could add 00:10:01 to the 1st log file time stamps and compare the logs.

So, increment the log 1 timestamps by 00:12:01. 
So Log 1 is now:

```
fn1-start 11:22:11
fn2-start 11:22:13
fn2-end   11:22:20
fn1-end   11:23:21
...
A long list
...
```

In this case, fn1 takes 20 seconds longer to complete after the fn2 function call  in log 2.

How can I achieve this? Which tools should I use? any alternate methods?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add more sample inputs and sample outputs in your post in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the timestamps from the files before comparing?

Comment: Have a look at `gawk` time functions, especially `mktime`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added the code samples. 
glennjackman Then there is nothing to compare as both the logs have same content other than timestamps.
kvantour I'll have a look Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compare the run times for individual functions as opposed to offsetting them so the first one start on the same time.

This means you need to calculate the function run time duration before comparing the two files. This can be done with a rather simple awk script:

```
function get_durations() {
  awk '
  BEGIN{
    # Split spaces and dashes
    FS="[ ]*|-"
  }

  /start/ {
    start[$1] = $3
  }

  /end/ {
    if($1 in start)
      end[$1] = $3
    else
      print "No corresponding \"start\" for function " $1 > "/dev/stderr"
  }

  # Function to convert timestamps into seconds using gnu coreutils date
  function timestamp_to_seconds(ts) {
    close(sprintf("date \"+%%s\" --date=\"%s\"", ts) | getline sec)
    return sec
  }
  END {
    for (x in start){
      if(end[x]){
        end_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds(end[x])
        start_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds(start[x])
        printf("%s %s\n", x, end_seconds - start_seconds)
      }
      else{
        printf("%s inf\n", x)
        print "No corresponding \"end\" for function " x > "/dev/stderr"
      }
    }
  }
  ' "${1}"
}
```

To compare the durations you can proceed in a similar way using awk arrays:

```
function compare_durations() {
  gawk -P '
    BEGIN{
      print "function,file1_duration,file2_duration,12_difference"
    }
    f[$1] {
      printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
        $1,
        $2,
        f[$1],
        ($2 == "inf" || f[$1] == "inf" ? "inf" : $2 - f[$1]))
    }
    !f[$1]{
      f[$1] = $2
    }
  ' "${1}" "${2}"
}
```

This function takes two files as inputs and prints out a csv with the comparison between the two files.

Finally you can use these functions together to compare the files:

```
compare_durations <(get_durations input1) <(get_durations input2) > summary.csv
```

> This solution assumes the function names don't repeat, if they do
>   repeat you can change the script to add a counter for each function.
>   The time complexity of the script is O(n) but it uses O(n) space, so
>   if you have really long logs you should find another approach.